# UPDATE performance when JOIN produces duplicates rows for columns in SET

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-12

Consider the following example:
There are 3 tables: `clients` (1) -> (n) `orders` (1) -> (n) `order_updates`.
I want to update `clients` based on the corresponding `order_updates` with `JOIN` (which produces duplicates for `clients` data):

```
UPDATE "clients"
SET "clients"."status" = 'active'
FROM "orders"
JOIN "orders_updates" ON "orders.id" = "order_updates"."order_id"
WHERE "clients"."status" <> 'active' AND
      "orders"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND 
      "order_updates"."created_at" > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 day')::date
```

Is it going to perform the same way (under the hood) as the following statement, which does not produce duplicates for the `UPDATE` statement?

```
UPDATE "clients"
SET "clients"."status" = 'active'
WHERE "clients"."id" IN (
  SELECT "orders"."client_id"
  JOIN "orders_updates" ON "orders.id" = "order_updates"."order_id"
  WHERE "clients"."status" <> 'active' AND 
        "orders"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND 
        "order_updates"."created_at" > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 day')::date
)
```

Which one is preferable? Please provide sources.

Comment: First optimization, created_at greater than yesterday is equal to today, no need for subtraction.

Comment: Why are table and field names in lowercase quoted, that's unnecessary. By the way what if a client is already 'active' and when is updated to 'inactive'?

Comment: If an `UPDATE` statement tries to update the same row twice, you typically get an error message. So it is clear that you want to avoid that, right?

Comment: @PepeNO it is an arbitrary query just to reflect the idea

Answer (score 2):

Please see the attached image of the explain plan for the two update statement approaches. It clearly demonstrates that the first approach will process duplicate rows, so the second approach (using IN clause) is preferable.

[update explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUb1t.png)

You can also refer this link, which explains the same about multi-table updates:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html :

"***When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_item list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.
Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than using a join.***"

Answer (score 1):

By default, the effectiveness will depend on the available indexes on the tables.

I think the 2nd option is preferable.
Provide the request execution plan(s). They can be analyzed and compared.

Consider another request option.

```
UPDATE "clients"
SET "clients"."status" = 'active'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT "orders"."client_id"
  JOIN "orders_updates" ON "orders.id" = "order_updates"."order_id"
  WHERE "orders"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND 
        "order_updates"."created_at" > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
)
```

Comment: the question is not about the most effective way to perform a query, but the mechanics of the update in case there is a join producing duplicate records

Comment: I'm about ``Which one is preferable?``.  Duplicates in JOIN and multiple updates are  acceptable.

Comment: ``EXISTS`` don't cause duplicate updates.

Answer (score 0):

Between the two approaches, the second one using the IN clause with a subquery is generally preferable in situations like this. This is because it avoids the possibility of duplicate updates for the same client, which can be both inefficient and potentially lead to incorrect results.

Comment: thank you for the response, can you provide any sources?